# post request alidate captcha c#

Tags: c#, request, http-post, recaptcha, captcha

I' coding a program that does post request on a website but sometimes (not always) there is a captcha to solve. (need to click on bus images).

I want to know how can I check if there is a captcha to validate (if so my program opens a window and the human solves it), if there is no captcha, the program continues.

When there is no captcha there is a g-recaptcha-response to put in the form but I have no idea what to put.
If there is a captcha I guess that when the person behind the computer solves it, google sends the g-recaptcha-response and I need to put it in the form.
is that correct?

thank you very much.

if you need more infos I will add everything.

edit add: [image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you must debug to live HTML website captcha HTML element id.

After that, you must query to response HTML.

If you find captcha element you must show captcha to the user.

Comment: i'll add the Html code of the website of the captcha

Comment: I added the picture of the code (couldn't get the html don't know why...) I know I need to use the data-site-key